# What would the Architecture of Uber, Lyft be like?

Tags: mobile, architecture, server

Please fill me up with the possible architecture of Uber, Lyft like applications and their servers. What kind of technologies they use? The protocols for mobile-server communication? (esp tracking the user/car location and updating them live)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vujVmugFsKc

This video explains a lot on server architecture and technology uber uses, but its bit old now. The speaker mentions 'mobiles update GPS data every 4 second', what would the protocol be in this case? Poker apps in common connects upto 9 players per table and updates the cards in realtime for each mobile, what protocol they use for mobile-server communication? technologies they use and architecture of their server?

Few useful links http://yalantis.com/blog/uber-underlying-technologies-works/

Comment: I will be interested in knowing if they use any sort of messaging platform for real-time communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stackshare lists this information:

- http://stackshare.io/uber
- http://stackshare.io/lyft

Answer (score 2):

You can get a good understanding of a companies basic stack by looking at their jobs page:

- https://www.uber.com/jobs/list?team=Engineering
- https://www.lyft.com/jobs